# Is there any way to edit specific line in a file without opening the file?

Tags: python, xml, file

I have an 18G XML file with some unwanted words as prefixes. I want to remove that part. It's tough to open such a big file and edit[RAM limitation]. Is there any way to open the file and edit that line and save it by code or command-line execution?

Comment: Look into SAX XML parsers, which allow you to parse element by element, vs keeping everything in memory (DOM parsers).

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Robert. I am using SAX XML parser as parsing XML contents but my XML file by itself is invalid as it contains this string - `This file contains X-entries.` just before the opening tag is started. I have to remove this part anyway to load into any parser beforehand.

Comment: If you ask questions about processing a large XML file, then anyone answering is going to assume that it's a good XML file, not a non-XML file that you want to convert to XML.